# MYSQL syntax - how to use where query with conditional statement in query

Tags: mysql

This is what i'm trying to query for example:

Code Example:

```
SELECT  IF(MAIN.PROCESS = 0,"YES","NO") AS `SUCCESS_LOG`, FROM `XLSX_UPLOAD` AS MAIN  WHERE `SUCCESS_LOG` LIKE 'NO'
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find what I'm doing wrong other than it's something related to the WHERE condition search.

Comment: You've managed to squeeze several errors into one tiny query. So it's hard to know where to begin. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `SUCCESS_LOG` is not a *real* field, you need to use `HAVING` to check on it.

```
HAVING `SUCCESS_LOG` LIKE 'NO'
```

Though, in this query, I would just check your `MAIN.PROCESS` (again).  That would probably be more efficient.

```
WHERE `MAIN`.`PROCESS` = 0
```

Comment: OMG - "HAVING" is the syntax! many thanks